# Retrieving email backup and mozilla bookmarks from command line

Tags: 12.04, installation, command-line

I can't get past the logon screen after upgrading to 12.04 so I want to get a email backup and mozilla bookmarks before reinstalling. Can someone help me on this.

---

I'm getting permission denied when trying to access the evolution folder and when I do the ~/.mozilla is says files does not exist

Comment: How do you try to access `evolution` and `mozilla` folders when you get access denied? With LiveCD? From tty1? Or other …?

Answer (score 4):

Supplement to Firefox backup.

If you want to backup Firefox with everything: bookmarks, history, plugins … do:

1. Backup `/home/USERNAME/.mozilla/xxx.default`
2. Copy it to the new install (Same location)

Now you have two choices.

#### One

1. Delete the existing xxx.default folder (added from new install).
2. Edit `/home/USERNAME/.mozilla/firefox/profiles.ini`
3. Change Path to match backup folder.

   ```
   [Profile0]
   Name=default
   IsRelative=1
   Path=xxxx.default # Change this line
   ```

#### Or two

1. Edit `/home/USERNAME/.mozilla/firefox/profiles.ini`
2. Add entry for backup-folder

   ```
   [Profile1]        # Profile1
   Name=backup       # Give a name 
   IsRelative=1
   Path=xxxx.default # Change to match backup folder
   ```
3. Start Firefox with `firefox -p` and select backed up profile.

Answer (score 2):

If your `/home` is on a separate partition (logical volume), as long as your don't re-format the partition when re-installing, all data should preserve (you can backup before reinstalling anyway, just to be safe).

To back up your email and firefox bookmarks, several options

1. CTRL + ALT + F1 (pseudo console), login and back up your email and bookmarks
2. If openssh is up and running, you can use `scp` or `rsync` to backup on a different host
3. If you prefer GUI, boot with a Ubuntu Live CD/DVD and mount your `/home`, back up your data in a Live Ubuntu Desktop session

Email
For Tunderbird, backup `~/.thunderbird`

For Evolution

user's data files
`$HOME/.local/share/evolution`

Various configuration and state files
`$HOME/.config/evolution`

Disposable data caches
`$HOME/.cache/evolution`

Configuration settings in GConf
`$HOME/.gconf/apps/evolution`

Refer to http://library.gnome.org/users/evolution/3.1/data-storage.html.en

Firefox bookmark in Firefox profile folder: `~/.mozilla/firefox/xxxxxx.default\bookmarks.html`, you may also want to backup the bookmarkbackups folder (all json)

Comment: I'm using evolution how do you get an archieve of that.

Comment: Updated the answer with Evolution.